# Twitter API get Parameters after Oauth

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth, django-allauth

I'm using Allauth for Twitter, works like a charm.

I have never worked with Scopes, so my question is, is there any support to get for example the twitter user stream?

Or anyone got any ideas how to get the request working?

I'm struggeling with the twitter api, it seems way more complicated then facebook or foursquare or any other api i have come across.

with facebook it's like this

```
return requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/%s&access_token=%s" % (path, access_token)).json()
```

Now if i send

```
requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json&oauth_consumer_key=' +oauth_con+ 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"&oauth_nonce="'+now+'"&oauth_token="'+twitter+'"&oauth_timestamp="'+now+'"&oauth_version=1.1"')
```

I get a either a 400 error or a 404 error depending on .json? or json&.
According to the doc you have to have "" around every parameter. Didn't help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?oauth_consumer_key=...&oauth_nonce=...`. ? instead of & in front of the first `GET`-Parameter.

Comment: yep i tried that as well and got a 400 error. I think something is wrong with my auth parameters but i can't figure out what

Comment: The oauth_version should be 1.0 and not 1.1.

Comment: @JonSusiak changed it, still get the 400 error